# Pulled from empty folder, now everything is on fire

Tags: git

'home_subfolder' is the path on disk inside my user account home folder in the 'home' root folder to the initial repo from which I meant to do a backup.

'usb_subfolder' is the path on disk in the 'media' root folder to the initial empty folder into which I wanted to do the backup above that points into a usb stick I mounted in the default Kubuntu KDE file manager way of mounting usb stick folder hierarchies.

Current situation is that 'git log' in both home_subfolder and usb_subfolder show the same hash with only one branch in both. From usb_subfolder 'git pull home_subfolder' is broken as in the original message.

Original message follows:

So I did

```
git pull home_subfolder
```

while in a usb_subfolder. Can't remember the immediate output, but it included a part about two repos having no commits in common. Would have been wiser for git to just error out with a message that in one of the folders there is no git repository.

At all times

```
git status
```

in home_subfolder gives

```
branch master
Working directory clean
```

This is so stupid considering the circumstances.

Doing again

```
git pull home_subfolder
```

at all times from usb_folder now returns U in front of 2 files in home_folder and A in front of another file and then says

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files
```

Had the bright idea to do

```
git clone home_subfolder
```

from the usb_subfolder because of my worries going away when

```
git status
```

in home_subfolder conforted me that there must be nothing bad about the situation. Therefore I suspect that now doing

```
git pull usb_subfolder
```

from home_subfolder will do the same broken result as above.

I do not want to resolve merge conflicts because git doesn't error out with a sane message of the situation when it should. I just want to get the home_subfolder and usb_subfolder repositories state to where it was before my breakage generating git pull and git clone commands.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, git 1.9.1.

Comment: Are `home_subfolder` and `usb_subfolder` branch names? Or separate repos? Or tags, or branches, or ... subdirectories? The naming convention suggests they are directories, which are not valid arguments for `git pull`. Providing _actual_ commands and output might allow us to help you, but this vague "I sorta remember running some things and there was some output, but I didn't really pay attention" kind of question isn't going to go very far...

Comment: 'git status' in home_subfolder gives 'branch master \n Working directory clean' is in the text of my question so it can be infered that home_subfolder is the initial git repo and usb_subfolder is the initial empty folder. Also was it you that downvoted? So nice helping people in need of help by shoving them off the cliff. Had there been an upvote/downvote option to other stackoverflow users on people's profile pages I would have downvoted on your's.

Comment: Also when you have a hazy recollection you don't just heaking say anything else than that you have a hazy recollection, so you are already wrong on 3 things: the clarity of which one was the empty folder, the downvoting of people in need and the hazy recollection thing.

Comment: JFTR here's [a thread on the Git mailing list started by the OP](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAEW+b659_v02v8z_dgWzVayb8ArBOD+O_Oky-F50JbJSP8vCKQ@mail.gmail.com/T/#r293e452e5c9f4ec121cc1a3a0c37ce3052761ad4).

Comment: @branco So nice for you to assume that I downvoted (I did not) and then threaten retaliation. That's not going to endear you to the community, and is likely to result in you getting even less help than you have so far. And the "in home_subfolder" could be just as easily interpreted as "in the subdirectory named home_subfolder in my bigger repo named my_repo" as it could be as "in the root directory of my repo named home_subfolder". Yes, there is some crossover there, but as currently written, there is a lot of ambiguity that complicates providing useful answers.

Comment: @twalberg 4th thing: how could anyone do the first command 'git pull home_subfolder' from anywhere else except a folder that IS NOT home_subfolder?

Comment: @twalberg >interpreted as ... subfolder in bigger repo< It may be a thing in git to pull/push to/from subfolders of a multi-git repositories containing git repository but I have no such situation in the question above. Also where would I put the root folder git repository, in /?

Comment: You keep using the term “subfolder”. What term does this relate to in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically somehow at the point when I investigated stuff on the usb stick I found the repository at the top level of the usb folder hierarchy. Therefore git got confused by what I was doing at usb_subfolder which is lower in the folder hierarchy and that is why it was having amasement inducing reports when trying to do a pull saying that pull is not possible because of unmerged and newly added files.